# Please suggest an application to convert photos to video

Tags: software-recommendation, video, conversion, photo

I need to convert some photos to video with all frames with special effects.
Video format can be mp4, 3gp, or mpeg4...

Please suggest a good application which will convert fast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try Imagination, a lightweight gui slideshow maker. Click [here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/imagination) to open it in Software Center.

Comment: but background music not playing :(

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/). In a simpe form you can do `ffmpeg -i image%d video.mpg`, but ffmpeg has [lots of options](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ffmpeg).

Answer (score 2):

Install OpenShot. It's a movie editor, but you can also put in some images and add cool transitions/effects.

Install openshot from the repos:

```
sudo apt-get install openshot
```

Or click on the following link: [OpenShot](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/openshot) [image: OpenShot]

Yours,
Daniel